# Sort numbers in a string variable separated by comma

Tags: php

I have the following string

```
$ickkcids = "120,176,182,120,182,207,176,120,182,118,120,176";
```

I want to display it in a ascending ordered, like below.

```
118(1) //118 is the lowest integer so it comes first.
120(4)
176(3)
182(3)
207(1) //207 is the highest integer so it comes last.
```

This is what im doing

```
$array = explode(',', $ickkcids); 
        sort($array); 
        foreach($array as $arraye)
        {
            $html .= $arraye.'<br />';
        }
```

But this returns all numbers in ascending order and i don't know how to count in this.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: try this, $array = explode(',', $ickkcids); sort($array);
var_dump($array);

Comment: DO you want to do it with PHP function or without function?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I have tried this by storing in array and used foreach to find the count but it is returing duplicate values.

Comment: [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) might help.

Comment: @AamirR this works but it shows all values and i want to get the count also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I support all above comments.First try your self, then ask a question.

Any way @OITE OMAN, you can try this code for your question:

```
$str = "120,176,182,120,182,207,176,120,182,118,120,176";
$array = explode(",",$str);
asort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
$latest_array = array_count_values($array);
print_r($latest_array);
foreach($latest_array as $key=>$value){
echo $key."(".$value.")";
echo "</br>"; 
}
```

Output:

```
118(1)
120(4)
176(3)
182(3)
207(1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much RameSh. But how do i get the values from the array - both number & count?

Comment: Which way you expecting output? tell me example.

Comment: Thanks for your support again. Say for example [120] => 4, I want to get $a=120 and $b=4. Similarly i have to get this for all the items in the array.

Comment: @OITEOMAN updated code and output, is this way you are expecting the output?

Comment: Yes @RaMeSh Also refer the comment by myself above.

Comment: @OITEOMAN In above example you can utilize $key and $value. ex: $key=120 and $value=4.

Comment: Thank you very much for the awesome support. Cheers.